# Max possible top in a given Stack (Nissan Interview Problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question**

You are given a stack of `N` integers. In one operation, you can either pop an element from the stack or push any popped element into the stack. You need to maximize the top element of the stack after performing exactly `K` operations. If the stack becomes empty after performing `K` operations and there is no other way for the stack to be non-empty, print -1.

*Input format :*

The first line of input consists of two space-separated integers `N` and `K`.
The second line of input consists `N` space-separated integers denoting the elements of the stack. The first element represents the top of the stack and the last element represents the bottom of the stack.

Output format:

Print the maximum possible top element of the stack after performing exactly `K` operations.

**Input:**

```
6 4
1 2 4 3 3 5
```

**Expected output:**

```
4
```

**Explanation for the expected output:**

In 3 operations, we remove `1, 2, 4` and in the fourth operation, we push `4` back into the stack. Hence, `4` is the answer.

**My code:**

```
 def stack_operations(list1, k):
    stack = []
    list1.reverse()
    for number in list1:
        stack.append(number) 
    if k == len(list1) or len(list1) == 1:
        print("-1")
    elif k > len(list1):
        print(max(list1))
    else:
        list2 = []
        for i in range(k - 1):
            list2.append(stack.pop())
        max_element = max(list2)
        print(max_element)

n, k = map(int, input().split())
num = list(map(int, input().split()))
stack_operations(num, k)
```

**My doubt:**

My code works for the sample input/output but it is showing run time error for all the other test cases. What am I doing wrong here? is the logic wrong or the code is wrong? Where's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're massively over-complicating the solution. Rather than attempt to debug your code, I would like to propose an entirely different way of thinking about the problem, which hopefully yields a one-line analytical solution.

**Interpretation 1**

In this version, I assume that you can only push back the last element that was popped.

Let's say you have the stack in the question, stored in list `s`:

```
s = [1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5]
```

If `k = 4`, the answer is trivial: pop 3, replace 1. What is important about this triviality is that it shows you that unless the next element is greater than everything in `s[:k - 1]`, you have to restrict yourself to the first `k - 1` elements. But you can't access all of those either. For example:

```
s = [1, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5]
```

There is no way to get `5` on top of the stack if `k = 4`: each take and replace is two operations. So that means that you have access to only every other element up to `k - 1`. In other words, for `k=4`, you can select from elements marked by `x` below:

```
s = [x, ., x, ., x, ., ., ., ...]
```

For `k=5`, the domain looks like this:

```
s = [., x, ., x, ., x, ., ., ., ...]
```

Hopefully the pattern is fairly apparent:

```
solution = max(s[k % 2:k + 1:2])
```

**Interpretation 2**

In this version, I assume that you can push back any item you popped.

Looking again at `k=4` and

```
s = [1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5]
```

You can pop of `1, 2, 4` in the first three (`k - 1`) operations. The fourth operation can either be to replace one of the items or expose the `k + 1`st element. So you have access to the first `k - 1` elements and to the `k + 1`st, but not the `k`th:

```
solution = max(max(s[:k - 1]), s[k])
```

**Note**

In both cases, handling `k < n` is left as an exercise for the reader. E.g., if `n == 1`, there is a solution only if `k % 2 == 0`, etc.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you can only push the value you just popped from the stack; this is equivalent to saying that you can't push at all, but can reduce `K` by any multiple of 2.  But the problem statement says "push any popped element into the stack", which I would interpret as meaning that *all* previous pops are still available for use.

Comment: @jasonharper. Well, that only makes it easier

Comment: @jasonharper. I added your interpretation too.

Comment: Can you tell me why we are printing `"-1"` when `k%2 ==1` ?

Comment: @shubhamprashar If I have one element in the stack and exactly one allowed operation, what happens? That about 2 elements? The rest is proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

I can't create comments (sorry) but 'n' is not defined. Unless code is missing when you check if "n == 1" that would throw an error.

Comment: edited, please check. Some test cases are still failing.

Comment: There's something funny going on in your 4th operation "for i in range(k-1):" create a list of values then you immediately 'pop' the last value and remove all the other values. If this is indeed what you want to do list2 should not be a list at all but a number. When you call 'max' there only ever one value so calling 'max' doesn't do anything

Comment: Don't be embarrassed we all go through this. I feel that the logic is off in that 4th operation. Are you able to debug your code so you can see what is happening? That is set breakpoints and run the code line by line.

Comment: Why would there be only one element in `list2`? I am popping elements in a loop and then appending them to list2 one my one. It is working fine for 86 test cases man. Use a print statement for the above test case and list2 will come out as `[1, 2, 4]`

Comment: My bad. I misread that block as the pop works differently in other languages I've used.